# How to overload operator> for a generic class in main.cpp

Tags: c++, overloading, operator-keyword

I've a question and I hope you know the answer. I've a generic heap class. Lets call it ***CHeap***. In this class, due to the nature of the heap, I need to compare the components (for example `Heap[i]>Heap[j]`). Here ***Heap*** is an ***array***.

If I define a variable like this in my ***main.cpp***:

```
cHeap <int> myHeap;
```

then I have no problem. But if I have a data structure, let's say:

```
struct S{
 int data;
 int code;
}
```

and I define:

```
cHeap <S> myHeap;
```

then I have problem. For example, I want the comparison be on ***code*** values. in other words: `Heap[i].code>Heap[j].code`

But, as I said before, this is a generic class and I don't want to have that in my code (in my ***CHeap*** class). Is there anyway that I can overload the ***operator>*** for ***CHeap*** in my ***main.cpp***?
In other words having:

```
bool operator>(const S& s1, const s& s2){
    return s1.code > s2.code;
}
```

in my ***main.cpp*** and link it to the ***CHeap*** class?

Something like what we do when we use STL's ***priority_queue***:

```
priority_queue <S, vector <S>, greater <S> > myPQ;

bool operator>(const S& s1, const s& s2){
    return s1.code > s2.code;
}
```

?!

Thanks

Comment: Why does it have to be in the main.cpp file? And what is the problem with the one you came up with? Also what does it mean to *link* something to a class?

Comment: @Jefffrey : because as I explained above, CHeap is a generic class. About link, I might have used the wrong word. I meant something like what we do in priority_queues. That's why I wrote it at the end to clarify what I'm looking for. If you know a better word please let me know :-)

Comment: I asked 3 questions, you answered one and I'm not even sure which one you answered.

Comment: Now I have one more: what is a *generic* class? You mean a *template* class?

Comment: @Jefffrey : Yes, generic class = template class

Comment: @Nejla BTW the correct term is "class template". Think of it as a template for making classes, not a class that is a template.

Comment: @juanchopanza: You are absolutely right. Sorry, I was in rush.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can write `operator>` in your `S` struct.

```
struct S{
 int data;
 int code;

 bool operator>(const S& other) { ... }
}
```

Also you can add another template argument to your `CHeap` class that will compare two `Type`:

```
template<typename T, typename Compare> 
class CHeap
{
    Compare comparer;
};
```

And for comparing to value use `comparer`:

```
if(comparer(object1, object2)) {} // If object1 is greater than object2
```

And write your `Compare` argument like this:

```
class SComparer
{
public:
    bool operator()(const S& s1, const s& s2) const { return s1.code > s2.code; }
}
```

Comment: It's not `public class`.

Comment: @juanchopanza Where is the problem?

Comment: @MohammadRB What Jeffrey said: `public class ....` is not C++. Other than that it looks fine, except your `SComparer` operator should probably be `const` too.

Comment: @juanchopanza ohhhhh, I always confuse C++ and C# conventions. Excuse Me

Answer (score 1):

You can define a `S::operator>()` overloading (it's a common practice)

```
struct S
{
    int data;
    int code;

    bool operator>(const struct S & aux) const
    {
        return this->code > aux.code;
    }
};
```

So, you can use it:

```
if (Heap[i] >Heap[j])
{
    ......
}
```

Comment: It looks like OP wants to be able to instantiate different heaps with different sorting criteria.

Comment: And what's wrong with the one he provided already? Your member function is exactly equivalent to his free function.